# How to calculate $(I + GH)^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Suppose we have a matrix A. We have decomposed A into a sum of the identity matrix and the product of two column(G) and row(H) matrices.
In general, how can we calculate $A^{-1}$?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17776/inverse-of-the-sum-of-matrices) question might help you. But I'm not certain.

Comment: The [Woodbury Matrix Idendity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) may help you as well.

Comment: @Eff More like Sherman–Morrison formula. Thanks;)

Comment: I believe you may be describing a *rank one* update to the identity matrix.  This has been discussed in a number of previous Questions, such as [Rank one perturbation proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791530/rank-one-perturbation-proof).

Comment: @hardmath Seems like they are the same. But the thing is I didn't quite know "Rand one perturbation" has anything to do with my question beforehand...

Comment: We are all here to learn!  It's a good question, just one that (in part disguised by non-obvious terminology) has come up before.  Note that if either $G=0$ or $H=0$, the "update" just gives us the identity matrix again.